# Elasticsearch DSL: Aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch

Shown below is the structure of type (kind of a table) of my data.

```
 Aircraft | Duration 
 A320     | 0.95
 A320     | 0.55
 A321     | 16.50
 A321     | 3.9
```

In this data, I want to perform a ceil() on duration, followed by a groupBy operation to get following output:

```
 Aircraft | Duration | Count
 A320     | 1        |  2
 A321     | 17       |  1
 A321     | 4        |  1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've based myself on the following mapping type (edited `Duration` as string):

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/tests -d '
{
  "mappings": {
    "test1": {
      "properties": {
        "Aircraft": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "Duration": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

And created four documents that match your data table above.

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/tests/_bulk -d '
{"index": {"_type": "test1", "_id": 1}}
{"Aircraft": "A320", "Duration": "0.95"}
{"index": {"_type": "test1", "_id": 2}}
{"Aircraft": "A320", "Duration": "0.55"}
{"index": {"_type": "test1", "_id": 3}}
{"Aircraft": "A321", "Duration": "16.50"}
{"index": {"_type": "test1", "_id": 4}}
{"Aircraft": "A321", "Duration": "3.9"}
'
```

The aggregation query that will return the results you expect would look like this:

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/tests/_search -d '
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "terms": {
          "Aircraft": [
            "a320",
            "b737"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "aircrafts": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "Aircraft"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "duration": {
          "terms": {
            "script": "Math.ceil(doc['Duration'].value as double)"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

The output of that query looks like this:

[image]

Note: Make sure to enable scripting in your `elasticsearch.yml` file by adding

```
script.disable_dynamic: false
```

Comment: thanks for suggesting a solution. My 'duration' is actually String. I tried "script": "Math.ceil( Double.parseDouble(  doc['Duration'].value ) )" but did not work. any suggestions.

Comment: thanks a lot. Just a side question. I have a filter clause to filter some specific aircraft. Example - { 
                "terms": { 
                    "aircraft":["a320", "b737"]     
                }. Where this should be inserted in the above query?

Comment: I've updated my answer, but note that the `icao_aircraft_type_actual` field is not in my mapping,so I've renamed it to `Aircraft`.

Comment: oops, edited that comment. I meant aircraft only. Thanks for the update.